# React JS Simple Application | SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I was trying to learn react js via this [Complete React Tutorial (with Redux)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9ij8CfkAY2RAGb-tmkNwQHG)
. But I am getting the following error in console.

> Error handling response: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at chrome-extension://jipinfggejlkpkomnccoocbdndjalicp/detect.js:43:25

Source :

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- v6 <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">
    </div>

    <script type="text/babel">

        class App extends React.Component {
            state = {
                name: 'Jonin',
                rank: 'A'
            }
            render() {
                return (
                    <div className="app-content">
                        <h1>Hi sensei!</h1>
                        <p>Rank : { this.state.name } ({ this.state.rank })</p>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.

Comment: Looks related to a Chrome extension instead of your app? Try in incognito

Comment: @yuriy636 you are right. In incognito there is no error.